# Dropbox sharing permissions

Tags: dropbox, shared-folders

I need to share a folder online with a colleague. We tried to use Dropbox and that works, but my colleague is not able to upload files on the shared folder.

Please any suggestion?

Comment: Shared folders count towards the quota of everyone who uses it. Is your colleague over quota?

Answer (score 0):

With dropbox, you can create shared folders with full read/write permissions.
Here is the [official guide](https://www.dropbox.com/help/19/en) to creating a shared folder on dropbox.

Dropbox is an easy to use application, if you only have a couple of folders that you would like to share, dropbox is easy to use and has multiple different sharing options. Read the dropbox help section for more info.

Comment: thanks Cubia, but apparently my colleague cannot UPLOAD files on the shared folder....

Comment: Does your colleague have dropbox installed? Or are you just sending him a link to the folder...

Comment: he has Dropbox installed

Comment: If he has dropbox installed, and the shared folder is in his dropbox folder, he can copy folders/files into that shared folder and dropbox will upload them automatically.

Comment: unfortunately apparently it is not working, I have tried it :-(((

Comment: You can go to dropbox.com, login, and check the options for that shared folder. Check the contents too, if your colleagues files are there, it would mean that your computer isn't syncing them. If they aren't there, ask your colleague to go on dropbox.com and upload a file from there.